# How to enable Cipher TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA on Windows server 2019 with AWS Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, tls1.2, amazon-elb, windows-server-2019

The website is on Windows server 2019 with the AWS Load Balancer with ELB SecurityPolicy-2016-08.  This policy definitely has the ECDHE_ECDSA cipher enabled. I have checked their docs. SSL certificate is installed on LB.

Running TLS Cipher Suites in PowerShell Windows server 2019 also shows these suits enabled but when running the website domain with SSLLabs or Zenmap. These suites are not appearing

TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

or even these:

TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

any ideas? the website is ASP.NetFramework 4.7. but I hardly think it has anything to do with the ciphers. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

[Zenmap Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yRly.png)

[AWS load balancer Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irBRO.png)

[PowerShell Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWHl5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Meta: this isn't about programming, and I'm not sure 'how to operate cloud' counts as development, so I authorize deletion if this is voted offtopic.

**Your server is irrelevant** and nothing you set or change on it will affect client(s).

You don't tell us [which AWS load balancer you use](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/features/#Product_comparisons) but to be at HTTPS level it must be Application or Classic, and in either case to do HTTPS it must **terminate the SSL/TLS protocol** -- in other words, the LB establishes one SSL/TLS connection with the client and decrypts the incoming request, parses it, and then optionally uses a *separate* SSL/TLS connection to the backend to re-encrypt, and reverses the process on the response: decrypt from the backend if necessary and re-encrypt to the client. See the line "SSL Offloading" well down in the table on that page; that's a jargon way of saying "LB does the SSL/TLS for the client, your server does not".

Thus the settings in the LB, only, control the SSL/TLS seen by the client(s). [ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html#describe-ssl-policies) which is the default (and I'm guessing that might be why you used it) excludes all DHE-RSA ciphersuites. (To avoid confusion, note the AWS webpage uses the OpenSSL names for ciphersuites, where RSA-only keyexchange is omitted from the name, whereas Zenmap/nmap uses the RFC names TLS_RSA_with_whatever.) It does *allow* ECDHE_ECDSA suites, but those will actually be negotiated, and thus seen by a scanner like Zenmap/nmap, only if you configure an ECDSA certificate and key -- which I bet you didn't.